# UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0

Tags: ios, uialertview, ios9, deprecated

I have tried several ways to use UIAlertController,instead of UIAlertView, but I cannot make the alert go. Thanks in advance for any further suggestions. I am a newbie.

*UIAlertView' was deprecated in iOS 9.0: UIAlertView is deprecated. Use UIAlertController with a preferredStyle of UIAlertControllerStyleAlert instead*

Here is my code :

```
import MessageUI

class SecondViewController: UIViewController,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func sendmail(sender: UIButton) {
           let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
        }
    }

    func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
        let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
        mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property

        mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["blabla@gmail.com"])
        mailComposerVC.setSubject("App Feedback")
        mailComposerVC.setMessageBody("Feature request or bug report?", isHTML: false)

        return mailComposerVC
    }

    func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
        let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        sendMailErrorAlert.show()
    }

    // MARK: MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate Method
    func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? I see your `UIAlertView` code but not your attempt at a `UIAlertController`. There are plenty of tutorials around. [Here](http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/) is one for example.

Comment: Update your question with your attempt to use `UIAlertController`. Explain what issue you are having. And do some searching. There are countless examples of how to use `UIAlertController`.

Answer (score 1):

use UIAlertController

Here a example:

```
   //Create the AlertController
  let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Swiftly Now! Choose an option!", preferredStyle: .Alert)

  //Create and add the Cancel action
  let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { action -> Void in
    //Do some stuff
    }
  actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
    //Create and an option action
  let nextAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: .Default) { action -> Void in
    //Do some other stuff
    }
  actionSheetController.addAction(nextAction)
  //Add a text field
  actionSheetController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { textField -> Void in
       //TextField configuration
     textField.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()
   }

   //Present the AlertController
   self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

self.presentViewController(sendMailErrorAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Could Not Send Email
     ", message: "Your device could not send e-mail.  Please check e-mail configuration and try again.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
```

Use UIAlertController 
After initializing add actions to alertcontroller.
UIAlertCOntroller is subclass of UIViewController. So you can use self.presentViewController method show alert on current controller.